# How to measure progress on a replatforming project?

Tags: architecture, microservices, project-management

I am working on re-platforming and migrating to microservice from an old monolithic application.

But I need a way to measure the success and progress of the project.

The things I thought about are:

- Measure the amount of code being deleted in the monolith
- Measure the number of calls that go to the old system vs to the new system

What do you think about the above? And is there any other way people are following in order to measure their progress?

Comment: What is the point of the progress meter? To indicate to the ops team which services have been migrated? To give business execs a rough % of how far along you are? To keep track of the work tasks that have been done? These three things can vary wildly in their relative size, e.g. you may have done 90% of the dev work to migrate a service which currently is not available in the new environment (so 0%) and this service might account for 50% of the platform requests. Your question is hard to answer without knowing what you intend to do with the information and who will need to see/understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) and the main reason is "To give business execs a rough % of how far along you are"  and "  To indicate to the ops team which services have been migrated"

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself why you are doing the migration. E.g. if you are doing the rewrite because the old monolith had slow response times, measure your average response time

(Kill It with Fire by Marianne Bellotti is a good resource on this topic)

Comment: This approach is liable to leave half-assed solutions when the problem in focus meets the "good enough" mark (or interest wanes, or other priorities emerge). How would you even list a response time as too slow, if not subjectively and with no actual relation to the codebase migration itself?